# Why Hibernate session object's delete method is not working?

Tags: java, hibernate

Why session object's delete method is not working in `GenericDAOImpl.java`, neither its giving any exception nor its showing any output. All other methods working fine expect `public void delete(T object)`, Please help me, Sorry if i asked this question in wrong way.

```
public class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements IGenericDAO<T> {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public GenericDAOImpl(Class<T> cl, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    if (sessionFactory == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Session factory is null!!!");
}

@Override
public T get(Class<T> cl, Long id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T element = (T) session.get(cl, id);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return element;
}

@Override
public T get(Class<T> cl, Serializable obj) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();     
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")   
    T element = (T) session.get(cl, obj);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return element;
}

@Override
public T save(T object) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(object);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return object;
}

@Override
public void update(T object) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(object);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}

@Override
public void delete(T object) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(object);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override   
public T findUniqueByQuery(String hsql, Map<String, Object> params) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery(hsql);
    if (params != null) {
        for (String i : params.keySet()) {
            query.setParameter(i, params.get(i));
        }
    }
    return (T) query.uniqueResult();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<T> query(String hsql, Map<String, Object> params) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery(hsql);
    if (params != null) {
        for (String i : params.keySet()) {
            query.setParameter(i, params.get(i));
        }
    }

    List<T> result = null;
    if ((hsql.toUpperCase().indexOf("DELETE") == -1)
            && (hsql.toUpperCase().indexOf("UPDATE") == -1)
            && (hsql.toUpperCase().indexOf("INSERT") == -1)) {
        result = query.list();
    } else {
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorround with try catch and see is there any exception

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Can you show a test?

Comment: thanks @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ now its giving `org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported` exception, but why ?

Comment: @Andres yeah i tested it

Comment: are you testing this for swing?

Comment: Before `beginTransaction()` check if check if there is already an open transaction.

Comment: @DouglasJunior you are right, on findUniqueByQuery method, i didnt committed the transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As investigated in comments, you are facing

> org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported exception

This is happening because you began transaction and never committed or rollbacked upon an exception.

I can see one of it's case in your code. See your code below

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

```
@Override   
public T findUniqueByQuery(String hsql, Map<String, Object> params) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery(hsql);
    if (params != null) {
        for (String i : params.keySet()) {
            query.setParameter(i, params.get(i));
        }
    }
    return (T) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

See, you began and never committed a transaction. Like wise check all other places in your project.

Comment: thanks @SURESH you are right,  when i made this changes  `T result = (T) query.uniqueResult();
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  return result;` then delete method is also working fine, thanks again bro :)

Comment: @PraveenRawat Glad to help Praveen.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Although I was not using transaction at all. I was using namedQuery like this :

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery(EmployeeNQ.DELETE_EMPLOYEES);
int rows = query.executeUpdate();
session.close();
```

It was returning 2 rows but the database still had all the records. Then  wrap up the above code with this :

```
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.getNamedQuery(EmployeeNQ.DELETE_EMPLOYEES);
int rows = query.executeUpdate();
transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

Then it started working fine. I was using SQL server. But I think if we use h2 above code (without transaction) will also work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported exception
```

Most probably you're not closing your session after an update or insert, and then you're doing the delete.